# MySQL selecting "previous" max(id) WHERE

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that inserts data when a kid checks in into a summer camp area.  If the kid is < than 12 years of age a parents barcode must be scanned to allow the kid entry into the young kids area (<12 years of age).

The table has the following columns.

```
kcID
uID
id
age
room
barcode
date
amber
```

The data will usually be presented like this.

```
kcID uID    id      age     room    barcode date                    amber
25   1      1       30      1000    0001    6/26/2014 1:27:40 AM    0
26   6      1       1       1000    0005    6/26/2014 1:27:40 AM    0
```

The problem I have is that I need to compare the dates/hours to know if the kid is entering or leaving the camp area and via php send an SMS to the parents so they know their kid is outside a particular area.

I know I can retrieve the max(kcID) WHERE barcode = XXXX and that will return the last inserted row, but, in order for me to retrieve said information the kid must be scanned, properly inserting a new row and rendering max(kcID) useless in this case.

What I need is to be able to select max(kcID) WHERE barcode = xxxx and then select the previous row record in which barcode = xxxx is found.  That way I can compare dates and know if the kid is leaving or entering that particular area.

The easiest solution I can think of right now is to have 2 tables (1 for entry 1 for out) and have the camp counselors choose if the kid is entering or leaving but I'm wondering if I can use only 1 table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a column indicating leave / return, and add this to your condition.

e.g.

```
ALTER TABLE `table`
    ADD `status` enum('left', 'returned') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'left';
```

a query would be

```
SELECT `kcID`, `barcode`
FROM `table`
WHERE `status` = 'left'
ORDER BY `timefield` DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a column with a status left and returned

```
ALTER TABLE `table` ADD `status` enum('left', 'returned') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'left';
```

now you can select a second last row by following query

```
select `kcID`, `barcode` from `table` where `status` = 'left' ORDER BY `barcode` DESC LIMIT 1,1
```